# How do I make a string with a " character in it? (Java)

Tags: java, string

Well that was pretty much my question, I need to do something like this:

```
String scriptContent = "print("Hello World")";
```

Comment: BTW, it's called "escaping" the quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for something called an *escape sequence*, which is a way of telling Java to interpret a particular character as something other than what it means by default.  In your case, you can make a Java string containing a double-quote by prefixing it with a slash:

```
String scriptContent = "print(\"Hello World\")";
```

There are many other escape sequences in Java.  For example, `\\` stands for a slash character itself (instead of the start of another escape sequence!); `\'` stands for a single quote; and `\n` stands for a newline.  There are many others; consult a Java reference for more details.

Comment: You only need the single quote escape for character literals, though.

Answer (score 8):

Use `\"`.

```
String scriptContent = "print(\"Hello World\")";
```

Comment: in your answer, the word "print" will not be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use escape character to do this

```
String scriptContent = "print(\"Hello World\")";
```

Answer (score 0):

apache commons has a StringEscapeUtils http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html