# Printing a " in a Java String

Tags: java, string, println

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I make a string with a " character in it? (Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840887/how-do-i-make-a-string-with-a-character-in-it-java)

I am having trouble printing a string like this in java `System.out.println("this is a "test"");` How can I go about this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
System.out.println("this is a \"test\"");
```

The `\` is called the **escape character**.

It is used to embed special characters into a `String` literal.

`\n` = newline

`\t` = tab

`\f` = form feed

`\r` = carriage return

`\"` = double quote

`\\` = backslash

this is just a few of the special characters you can insert with an escape sequence.

Answer (score 9):

The way you escape special characters in Java is using `\`. E.g. this (`"\\"`) is how you return `\` and this (`"\""`) is how you return `"`.

This is how you may implement your example:

```
System.out.println("this is a \"test\"");
```

Comment: I wonder the same, you tell me.

Comment: it was downvoted because before the edit this answer was wrong.

Comment: It was a typo, if you see the revision before the wrong answer, it was right.

Answer (score 2):

escape the quote

```
System.out.println("this is a \"test\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

You must escape the " characters in Java

```
System.out.println( "this is a \"test\"");
```